# Customize date in Jquery for Json data

Tags: jquery, json

This is the Json data I receive from service part.

```
"session": 
        {
            "startTime": "08:00:00", // <--
            "sessionId": 231,
            "endTime": "09:00:00",  // <--
            "eventId": 100,
            "maxSeats": 0,
            "maxWaitlisted": 0,
            "modifiedUser": "TestUser",
            "modifiedDate": "2010-12-07",  // <--
            "sessionDate": "2010-12-01",  // <--
            "numberOfAttendees": 0,
            "sessionName": "SessionName1",
            "sessionStatusCode": "Open",
            "cancelledInd": "No",
            "cancellationEmailText": "Not",
            "seatsRegistered": 0,
            "seatsWaitlisted": 0,
            "user_id": null,
            "updateFlag": "R"
        }
```

Using jquery I need to display `"2010-12-01"` in `"Wed, Dec 01"` Format in my HTML. Appreciate the Help

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://phpjs.org/functions/date:380

by using this function you can display date in any format u like

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the convert the value of "sessionDate" to a Date object, then get the weekday from the Date object, no jQuery needed.:

```
var sessionDate_to_printDate = function(sessionDate) {
  var weekdays = new Array(
    "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
  var months = new Array(
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

  var dateObj = new Date( Date.parse(sessionDate) );

  return weekdays[dateObj.getDay()] + ", "
       + months[dateObj.getMonth()] + " "
       + dateObj.getDate();
}
```

Usage example:

```
sessionDate_to_printDate("2011-01-04");
```

should yield `"Tues, Jan 4"` (in the PST timezone)

Comment: Code var dateObj = new Date( Date.parse(sessionDate) ); is returning me 1 July 1970. It is not taking Json data to convert to Date object.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Are you calling like the following:

sessionDate_to_printDate( someJSONObject.session.sessionDate );

Comment: Creating a var out of Json data, then passing this var to function. Current issue is it is not able to parse "SessionDate" , i tried using parseInt even. Code pattern var aa = Json.sessionDate, function customizeDate(aa) 
       {var tt = sessionDate.toString();
   var weekdays = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
var dateObj = new Date( Date.parse(aa) );return weekdays[dateObj.getDay()] + ", "+ months[dateObj.getMonth()] + " "+ dateObj.getDate();
    }

Comment: Two things:  1) in your customizeDate() function, you create a 'tt' variable, but Date.parse() is still parsing the 'aa' variable.  2) Try using the following to make sure that 'Json' is an actual JSON object and not just a string: "alert( typeof Json );" If that returns "object" it's JSON. If you get "string", then it's a string.